# Video Conversion (a la youtube)

Tags: php, flash, html, video-processing

So we were going to make a website allowing users to upload video. The website is going to be in PHP/MySQL. Are there any converters out there available for PHP to convert a video from a given format to flash to display on the web page to play?

Basically we would have a file on the server in say .avi format, or quicktime format. How do I grab it from the server, convert it to flash and display it on the php page to play?

Also, does can I use the video capabilities of HTML5 with PHP to make any of this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have seen is encoding to flash on the server uses FFMPEG, Which must be installed onto the hosting server (some hosts specialize in this market). I've also looked for an open source encoder PHP or Perl, and not found one. I believe the problem is flash has not been open source and that stopped people because of licensing issues.

Comment: If you want to use a Flash player, convert the video to .FLV. If you want to use the new HTML5 video tag, convert it to .m4v. You can check out this nice HTML5 player: http://www.html5video.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VideoToolkit php class, that uses ffmpeg and mencoder to convert the videos.
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html